# Adding number to a string?

Tags: java, sql

I have 3 columns in a table, time_in, time_out, new_time_out

In getting the time_in, I used the following codes:

```
Calendar cal= new GregorianCalendar();        
                int hour=cal.get(Calendar.HOUR);
                int minute=cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
                int second=cal.get(Calendar.SECOND);

                label_time.setText(hour+":"+minute+":"+second);
```

In time_out:

```
if(a.equals("1")) {
            b = ((hour+1)+":"+minute+":"+second);
        }
        else if(a.equals("2")) {
            b = ((hour+2)+":"+minute+":"+second);
        }
```

Where b is my time out. I declared it as a string. Now for the new_time_out, I want it to be like, if the user chooses 1, It will be added to the hour of the time_out. Same if he chooses 2. For example:

My time_out(b) is 9:45:21 and the user chooses 2. The new_time_out will be 11:45:21. My time out is also a string.

Comment: so.. you are not getting the o/p???.. what is happening??

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: @gbejic - I want to add 1 or 2 to time_out then the result will be the new_time_out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your initial input must remain as a String, you could split the String, do the math, and then join it back together as a String again. Example:

```
String time_out = "9:45:21"; // starting time
String[] parts = time_out.split(":"); // split into 3 parts
parts[0] = Integer.toString(Integer.parseInt(parts[0]) + 2); // add two to hours

String new_time_out = parts[0]+":"+parts[1]+":"+parts[2]; // recreate string        
System.out.println(new_time_out);
```

Which will output:

```
11:45:21
```

Answer (score 0):

You start off with integers. You'll have to add an integer by doing:

```
Calendar cal= new GregorianCalendar();        
int hour=cal.get(Calendar.HOUR);
int minute=cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
int second=cal.get(Calendar.SECOND);

hour += (int);
minute += (int);
second += (int);

hour.toString();
minute.toString();
second.toString();

label_time.setText(hour+":"+minute+":"+second);
```

What the toString() method does is, it takes the integers and turn them into strings.

Comment: Are you sure your code will compile? What is `+= (int);` doing ? Then your toString() methods are affecting none variable...

Comment: No, it wouldn't compile :)

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using Calendar, why not utilize its' functions:
You have:

```
Calendar cal= new GregorianCalendar();
int hour=cal.get(Calendar.HOUR);
int minute=cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
int second=cal.get(Calendar.SECOND);

String timeIn = (hour+":"+minute+":"+second);
```

Now, you can add 2 hours by using add() function http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/GregorianCalendar.html#add(int, int), which takes 2 arguments:

- int field
- int amount

> public void add(int field, int amount)
>
> Adds the specified (signed) amount of time to the given calendar field, based on the calendar's rules.

So you could do this:

```
cal.add(Calendar.HOUR, 2);

hour=cal.get(Calendar.HOUR);
minute=cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
second=cal.get(Calendar.SECOND);

String newTimeOut = (hour+":"+minute+":"+second);
```

So just get user's input, eg:

```
int hoursToAdd = some value
```

and do:

```
cal.add(Calendar.HOUR, hoursToAdd);
```

You can also add to other fields, such as Calendar.MINUTE, Calendar.SECOND etc. See the link.

NOTE: add() will automatically handle cases when you're adding hours that would make no sense with string based approach without checking the conditions, eg. add 20h to time 11:00:00, and you'll get 7:00:00 next day, unless of course you want to have 31:00:00.